# Having trouble adding lightbox to my site. Just getting a page with just the picture instead of the pop up

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Ok so I'm learning lightbox for the first time. I'm trying to use it with this bootstrap template I downloaded which made it easy to put in the images and customize the navbar. Right now when I click the image, it brings me to a page with JUST the image. No pop up. Right now I'm focusing on just gallery1.jpg if you look at the HTML. Am I missing something? Hope this isn't confusing, thanks.
I am trying to use fancyBox for the lightbox add on.

Do I have the javascript location typed up incorrectly? http://i.imgur.com/pCgZkKA.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>4 Col Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Template</title>


<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/4-col-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- lightbox stuff -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css"             media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color:#F60;">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-        example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../startbootstrap4/index.html"><img src="logonav.png"</a></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery1.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Gallery

            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Projects Row -->
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item"> 
       <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/gallery1.jpg" data-lightbox="fancybox" data-    title="untitled"><img src="images/gallery1.jpg"></a> 
       </div>            

       <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery2.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery10.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery4.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Projects Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery5.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery3.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery9.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery8.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Projects Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery7.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery6.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery11.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/gallery12.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery1.html">&laquo;</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="gallery1.html">1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery2.html">2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery3.html">3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">4</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="gallery2.html">&raquo;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <footer>
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading jQuery twice:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

and at the end

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

remove the second one.